# Reporting Services - getting data from https SOAP API

Tags: datasource

Is it possible to create a data source in reporting services to pull data from a https data source?
I have successfully managed to create reports that pull from various http SOAP APIs, but when I try to connect to a https data source I get an error.
The error coming back from the webservice is not very descriptive -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>An error has occurred while consuming this service. Read the Detail property for further information.</faultstring><faultactor>GetExceptionPolicy</faultactor><detail>An error has occurred while consuming this service. Please contact your administrator for more information. Error ID: a90b9112-c09b-438d-b58b-4dfb852658ce</detail></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

The webservice I'm calling is logging the request that SSRS sent in a database, and it is storing it with a leading "?" -

```
?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetBiller xmlns="http://tempuri.org">
      <AgentID>1</AgentID>
    </GetBiller>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```